Demander “et toi ?”
« Dans ma famille il y a trois personnes. Et toi ? »
« Dans ma famille il y a 5 personnes »
“Et toi ?” est correct ici ? Le sujet n’est pas « tu » et je ne suis pas sûr que ça c’est correct.

Ça se comprend, mais   un côté gauche qui s'en dégage n'en fait pas vraiment du bon français.

En fait, la deuxième phrase n'a pas le même sujet que la première; c'est la version raccourcie d'une autre phrase:
Dans ma famille il y a trois personnes. Et toi, combien de personnes as-tu dans ta famille?
"Et toi" (répétition du sujet) est fait pour insister sur l'interpellation (une sorte d'effet de style). A elle seule, cette partie représente le reste.
Je comprends ton interrogation toutefois, car cela pourrait aussi être:
Dans ma famille il y a trois personnes. Combien de personnes y a-t-il dans la tienne/Combien la tienne en a-t-elle?
Et là, nous serions restés sur de la 3e personne au lieu de la 2e.
Mon opinion sur ce choix, est qu'en français contemporain, on utilise "et toi?" dans une conversation principalement pour attirer l'attention de son interlocuteur. L'autre se sent plus "concerné" par cette interpellation directe, et cela rend la discussion plus vivante. D'autre part, bien sûr, ces deux mots permettent d'éviter d'écrire la question complète qui est sous-entendue avec le contexte, même avec un changement de pronom.

En complément de la réponse d'Ety, la phrase proposée dans la question se comprend mais n'est pas très idiomatique. On est rarement inclus dans Il y a, il manque une virgule après famille et Et toi est un peu inattendu. On entendra plutôt:

Dans ma famille, on est trois; et dans la tienne ?

ou

Chez nous, on est trois; et chez toi ?

